# Java connect four bit wise functions and bit board errors

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, artificial-intelligence, bitboard

Essentially im trying to create a connect four Ai and i came across an [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-the-perfect-connect-four-ai-bot-c165115557b0) which uses bit boards to optimize making moves and checking for wins. Essentially i took a few methods from a git hub [readme](https://github.com/denkspuren/BitboardC4/blob/master/BitboardDesign.md) which are supposed to make a move and undo a move on your bit board unfortunately it appears that the methods are not working properly because it's placing ones at the end of the bit string instead of spacing them by 7. I assume this is probably some java thing that is preventing these from working correctly and i have posted a sample program below which i think demonstrates the problem accurately. For example if i set a long variable so that it has a row of four ones on the 5th row and display it. It displays correctly without the beginning zeros but on the other hand if i add three tokens to the first column. And then three tokens to the third column. It displays as 111, and 111. When it should be

```
000000000000000000000000011100000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000111
```

and without the leading zeros so

```
11100000000000000
111
```

Then if i run another test with these colum drops 1,3,1,3,2,4
which should result in this board state.

```
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| X |   | O |   |   |   |   |
| X | X | O | O |   |   |   |
-----------------------------
```

It displays 10, 10 when it should be

```
000000000000000000001000001100000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000010000011
```

or

```
1000001100000000000000
10000011
```

Here is some testing code which demonstrates this second scenario. At this point im at a loss because the operations of these methods are quite elegant and complex although they are only 3 lines of code it would be greatly appreciated if anyone could tell me whats wrong with what im doing. Cheers!

```
public class EConnectFour {
    private static int[] height = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    private static int counter = 0;
    private static int[] moves = new int[42];
    private static long[] bitBoard = new long[2];



    public static void main(String[] args) {
          long TOP = 0b0000000001000000100000010000001000000000000000000L;
          System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(TOP));
          makeMove(1);
          makeMove(3);
          makeMove(1);
          makeMove(3);
          makeMove(2);
          makeMove(4);
          System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(bitBoard[0]));
          System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(bitBoard[1]));
    }

    private static boolean isWin(long board) {
        int[] directions = {1, 7, 6, 8};
        long bb;
        for(int direction : directions) {
            bb = board & (board >> direction);
            if ((bb & (bb >> (2 * direction))) != 0) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static void makeMove(int column) {
        long move = 1L << height[column]++;
        bitBoard[counter & 1] ^= move; 
        moves[counter++] = column;  
    }

    private static void undoMove() {
        int column = moves[--counter];
        long move = 1L << --height[column];
        bitBoard[counter & 1] ^= move;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this line suppose to do? `long move = 1L << height[column]++;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inadvertently kept dropping tokens into the same first slot.

Replace:

```
// long move = 1L << height[column]++;
long move = 1L << (height[column]++ + ((column-1) * height.length));
```

Your reference to `column` is off by one (arrrays in Java are 0-indexed). At the end of your run, the height looks like this:

```
height = [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0]
```

You can fix that with:

```
long move = 1L << (height[column-1]++ + ((column-1) * height.length));
```

Final version of makeMove:

```
private static void makeMove(int column) {
    long move = 1L << (height[column-1]++ + ((column-1) * height.length));
    bitBoard[counter & 1] ^= move; 
    moves[counter++] = column;  
}
```

Version of undoMove:

```
private static void undoMove() {
    int column = moves[--counter];
    moves[counter] = 0;  
    long move = 1L << (--height[column-1] + ((column-1) * height.length));
    bitBoard[counter & 1] ^= move;
}
```

Comment: How might i modify the undoMove method to reverse this?

Comment: @JulianCarrier Can you provide moves and a result as an addition to your question, below the initial question? I can most likely fix it, but I think it's the same as in the makeMove.

Comment: right it is the same problem as makeMove but reverse. If we have the same sample program with the same column drops the undoMoves should revert the bitboard back to one turn earlier so say we have these as our bitboards.                           000000000000000000001000001100000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000010000011. One undo move should revert it back to 
000000000000000000000000001100000000000000 000000000000000000000000000000000000000011.

Comment: @JulianCarrier The principal is the same. I only found the answer because I debugged the entire thing with System.out.println  :)

Comment: @JulianCarrier new version of `undoMove()`